# Why my Lualatex can't find spring layout

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs

I am trying to draw my spring layout graph, but I am getting and error, which says that spring layout is unknown. P.s. I works with all other layout for example necklace. What could be wrong my code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{geometry}
 \geometry{
 a4paper,
 total={210mm,297mm},
 left=5mm,
 right=5mm,
 top=20mm,
 bottom=20mm,
 }
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{graphdrawing}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
\usegdlibrary{trees}
\usegdlibrary{circular}
\definecolor{burntorange}{cmyk}{0,0.52,1,0}
\definecolor{violet}{cmyk}{0.79,0.88,0,0}
\def\oran{orange!30}
\tikzstyle{vertex}=[draw,circle,burntorange, left color=\oran,text=violet,minimum width=20pt]
\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}[spring layout, node distance=50pt]
\node (0) [vertex] {0};
\node (1) [vertex] {1};
\node (2) [vertex] {2};
\node (3) [vertex] {3};
\node (4) [vertex] {4};
\node (5) [vertex] {5};
\node (6) [vertex] {6};
\node (7) [vertex] {7};
\node (8) [vertex] {8};
\node (9) [vertex] {9};
\path (0) edge[--] (1); 
\path (0) edge[--] (2); 
\path (0) edge[--] (3); 
\path (1) edge[--] (4); 
\path (3) edge[--] (5); 
\path (3) edge[--] (6); 
\path (2) edge[--] (7); 
\path (7) edge[--] (8); 
\path (5) edge[--] (9); 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add `\usegdlibrary{force}`.

Comment: Wow, I have missed this... Thank you for help! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `spring layout` is part of the `force` library. So you have to add `\usegdlibrary{force}`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{geometry}
 \geometry{
 a4paper,
 total={210mm,297mm},
 left=5mm,
 right=5mm,
 top=20mm,
 bottom=20mm,
 }
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{graphdrawing}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
\usegdlibrary{trees}
\usegdlibrary{circular}
\usegdlibrary{force} % <-- ADD LIBRARY !!!
\definecolor{burntorange}{cmyk}{0,0.52,1,0}
\definecolor{violet}{cmyk}{0.79,0.88,0,0}
\def\oran{orange!30}
\tikzstyle{vertex}=[draw,circle,burntorange, left color=\oran,text=violet,minimum width=20pt]
\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}[spring layout, node distance=50pt]
\node (0) [vertex] {0};
\node (1) [vertex] {1};
\node (2) [vertex] {2};
\node (3) [vertex] {3};
\node (4) [vertex] {4};
\node (5) [vertex] {5};
\node (6) [vertex] {6};
\node (7) [vertex] {7};
\node (8) [vertex] {8};
\node (9) [vertex] {9};
\path (0) edge[--] (1); 
\path (0) edge[--] (2); 
\path (0) edge[--] (3); 
\path (1) edge[--] (4); 
\path (3) edge[--] (5); 
\path (3) edge[--] (6); 
\path (2) edge[--] (7); 
\path (7) edge[--] (8); 
\path (5) edge[--] (9); 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image: force]

---

The default `inner sep` is `.3333em`. For more information have a look at the manual in section 17.2.3. Usually this looks quite nice, but in your case it can make the nodes unproportionally big if you put bigger numbers in your nodes. So what you want to do is remove the inner separation and control the size of the nodes solely with `minimum width`:

```
\tikzstyle{vertex}=[draw,circle,burntorange, left color=\oran,text=violet, inner sep=0, minimum width=20pt]
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image: force_2]

Comment: one question, How to make that circles smaller? Because if I add more elements that circles is getting random sizes values.

Comment: You mean if you reduce the value of `minimum width` and then add a node with e. g. `100` as text, the `100` node is bigger than the others? And you don't want this behavior?

Comment: Assuming this is what you meant, have a look at my updated answer.